# Jetpack Compose remember state and re-renders

Tags: android, performance, state, android-jetpack-compose, render

**Case A**

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Parent(viewModel: VM = hiltViewModel()) {
    val stateA by remember { viewModel.stateA }
    val stateB by remember { viewModel.stateB }

    Column {
        ChildA(stateA = stateA)
        ChildB(stateB = stateB)
    }
}

@Composable
fun ChildA(
    stateA: StateA
) {
    ...
}

@Composable
fun ChildB(
    stateB: StateB
) {
    ...
}
```

**Case B**

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Parent(viewModel: VM = hiltViewModel()) {
    Column {
        ChildA(viewModel = viewModel)
        ChildB(viewModel = viewModel)
    }
}

@Composable
fun ChildA(
    viewModel: VM
) {
    val stateA by remember { viewModel.stateA }
    ...
}

@Composable
fun ChildB(
    viewModel: VM
) {
    val stateB by remember { viewModel.stateB }
    ...
}
```

Most examples I see out there are **Case A** shouldn't we be using **Case B**?

Unless compose do some magic I don't know about shouldn't **Case A** re-render the `Parent` `ChildA` and `ChildB` for every state change of `stateA` and `stateB` while **CaseB** will only re-render `ChildA` for `stateA` changes and `ChildB` for `stateB` changes?

can someone explain it and point to some official doc about this specific issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Compose checks if a recomposition can be skipped or not based on  the parameter's value and parameter's stability.

If you want to have more testable and reusable composables you could have **case A** with only the parameters needed to render it and also have the actions delegated to the parent.

This doesn't come for free you have to use either primitives, immutable or stable clases, and check for another less intuitive cases like the use of lambdas vs method references if you want to have the minimal recompositions...

**Official recommendation** says to only worry when performance is an issue, and it gives a list of things to check in case that happens.

Here is a more detailed explanation about it: [More performance tips for Jetpack Compose](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahXLwg2JYpc)